# How to link the readline library to an object file?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, readline, fasm

I'm trying to use the GNU readline library in a program written in FASM. This is my assembly code:

```
format elf64

public _start

extrn readline

section ".text" executable
_start:
    push prompt
    call readline
    jmp  _start

section ".data"
    prompt db ">> ", 0
```

Then I compile and link it as follows:

```
$ fasm test.asm
$ ld -lreadline test.o -o test
```

However when I try to execute `./test` bash gives me the following error message:

```
bash: ./test: No such file or directory
```

The `test` executable is present in the directory. What's wrong? Am I not linking the `libreadline` library correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me once when I was on a 64-bit system compiling code for 32-bit. You have to install some additional 32-bit development tools and libraries (like an appropriate variant of libc) so that 32-bit binaries can be recognized as executable as well.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Which packages do you believe I need to install?

Comment: @AaditMShah Well, I don't know off of the top of my head, it's been a long I've used Ubuntu the last time.

Comment: I have seen this on straight 32-bit code. `ld`, by default, tried to use `/lib/ld-linux.so.1`as an interpreter/dynamic linker... which does not exist (on my system). (you can see this in a straight text-dump of the file) Solution is `ld -I/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ...` (`--dynamic-linker` is an alias for `-I`,   if you like more typin'). Location on your system may be different, but I think this is what you've encountered. Confusing, aint it? May need to specify `-l readline` (and possibly `L path-to-libreadline` too)